# Does Google Test auto-registration avoid the static initialisation order fiasco?

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest, static-order-fiasco

Using Google Test with c++11, if tests are defined across separate compilation units, is the auto-registration mechanism vulnerable to the static initialisation order fiasco?

If not, why not?

EDITED TO ADD:

Specifically:  As I understand it, the standard allows the initialisation of the static members of the test classes in other compilation units to occur *after* entry to `main()`.

The `UnitTest::GetInstance()` method guarantees that the `UnitTest` registry is created on first access.  But what stops that first access being the invocation of the main `Run()` method from `main()`, before any tests are registered?

Perhaps the key is that they are static class members, not static free variables?

Answer (score 1):

Each `TEST` macro expands into a test class with static field, which will be initialized with a call to [`MakeAndRegisterTestInfo()`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L2522) that will access tests registry in function-scoped static variable in [`UnitTest::GetInstance()`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L3964). This variable will be initialized at first use and tests registry will correctly register tests one by one even though the order of tests registration is not defined because they are registered when corresponding static fields are initialized.

Comment: Please see the clarification I've added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer to an equivalent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45212555/193887), the answer is:

**Yes, Google Test's auto-registration mechanism is vulnerable to the static initialisation order fiasco.**

If the tests are defined in other compilation units, whether they are registered before `RUN_ALL_TESTS()` is invoked depends on compiler-specific behaviour.