# Deferred initialisation order in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, static-order-fiasco

Consider the following code, split across three compilation units:

`a.h`:

```
struct A
{
    void Register(const char* s);

    const char* m_s[10];
    int m_i = 0;
};

A& GetA();
```

`a.cpp`:

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void A::Register(const char* s)
{
    m_s[m_i++] = s;
}

A& GetA()
{
    static A instance;
    return instance;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A& a = GetA();
    int n = a.m_i;
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", a.m_s[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

`b.cpp`:

```
#include "a.h"
struct B
{
    B() { GetA().Register("b"); }

    static B* instance;
};
B* B::instance = new B;
```

`c.cpp`:

```
#include "a.h"
struct C
{
    C() { GetA().Register("c"); }

    static C* instance;
};
C* C::instance = new C;
```

The code builds and runs fine using gcc (-std=c++11), producing the output:

```
c
b
```

Now, referring to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables):

> **Deferred dynamic initialization**
>
> It is implementation-defined whether dynamic initialization
>   happens-before the first statement of the main function (for statics)
>   or the initial function of the thread (for thread-locals), or deferred
>   to happen after.
>
> If the initialization of a non-inline variable is
>   deferred to happen after the first statement of main/thread function,
>   it happens before the first odr-use of any variable with static/thread
>   storage duration defined in the same translation unit as the variable
>   to be initialized. If no variable or function is odr-used from a given
>   translation unit, the non-local variables defined in that translation
>   unit may never be initialized (this models the behavior of an
>   on-demand dynamic library). However, as long as anything from a TU is
>   odr-used, all non-local variables whose initialization or destruction
>   has side effects will be initialized even if they are not used in the
>   program.

Note that `a.cpp` is unaware of the existence of `B` and `C`, and that the only interactions of `B` & `C` with `A` are the invocations of `GetA()` and `A::Register()` during construction of their respective instances.

As far as I can see, the `B` & `C` instances are not ODR-used, and certainly not from `main()`'s translation unit.  Their initialisation clearly has side effects, but it seems to me that there's no guarantee that this initialisation will occur before entry to `main()`, or before `main()` prints the registered strings - or indeed at all.

So - finally - **my question is this**:  Is the fact that the `B` and `C` instances are initialised before `main()` prints the registered strings due *not* to the standard, but instead to gcc's implementation-defined behaviour?

If it is guaranteed by the standard, how?

Comment: What's bad about dynamic initialization is their relative order cross translation unit is undefined. But most compilers support `__attribute__((init_priority(x)))`

Comment: @StoryTeller: What guarantees that, if they are initialised, it will only be before main is executed?

Comment: Apparently nothing. I was reading the wrong section. Had static initialization in mind, and applied it to dynamic initialization. The only guarantee in main is that `B::instance == nullptr` before main begins execution.

Comment: Which makes your question quite interesting, given all the implementation defined behavior present :)

Comment: There's also the note in this paragraph to consider (about the points execution for dynamic initialization): ["Such points should be chosen in a way that allows the programmer to avoid deadlocks"](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#4). I would argue that this applies in a broader sense. If `A` is odr used in main, the compiler can't inject initialization for `B` and `C` willy-silly, since it might interfere with `A`. Therefore it must be sequenced either entirely before main starts executing, or entirely after.

Comment: Note 36 to that section is also interesting (and similar wording appears in the C++11 standard) - but it still doesn't clarify _when_ initialisation occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the fact that the `B` and `C` instances are initialised before `main()` prints the registered strings due not to the standard, but instead to gcc's implementation-defined behaviour?

It is **not** guaranteed by standard. The most relevant part of the quote:

> If no variable or function is odr-used from a given translation unit, the non-local variables defined in that translation unit may never be initialized

Since no function, nor variable has been odr used from `b.cpp` nor `c.cpp`, their static variables may be uninitialized (in regard to dynamic initialization) and therefore the side-effects of their initialization might not be visible.

---

In practice, I would expect the shown, initializing behaviour when the translation units are statically linked, and the possible non-initializing behaviour when they are dynamically loaded (shared library). But neither is guaranteed by the standard, as it doesn't specify how shared libraries behave.

Comment: The C++11 standard says: "A non-local variable with static storage duration having initialization with side-effects must be initialized even if it is not
odr-used." (Note 34) But it still doesn't clarify _when_ this must happen relative to any statements in `main()`.

Comment: @Jeremy notes are not normative. It appears to conflict with the rule that gives an exception to TU's whose variables / functions are not odr-used: *"However, **as long as anything from a TU is odr-used**, all non-local variables whose initialization or destruction has side effects will be initialized even if they are not used in the program."* When a rule conflicts with a note, the rule stands, and the note doesn't.

Comment: @Jeremy My copy of the draft (much later than C++11) notes: *"A non-local variable  with static storage duration having initialization with side effects is initialized in this case, even if it is
not itself odr-used"* where I believe "*in this case*" refers to *"before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the
same translation unit ..."*. So, this conflict seems to have been resolved.

Comment: Yes, I agree the conflict in the wording appears to be resolved post-C++11 - leaving us with the upshot that "It is implementation-defined in which threads and at which points in the program such deferred dynamic initialization occurs."  So in theory a perverse compiler could choose to do all such initialisation on exit.

Comment: @Jeremy well, if nothing from that TU is odr-used, then it doesn't need to be initialized at all. But I suppose initializing at exit would also be conforming in that case; just pointless. If *something* (anything from that TU) is used, then the dynamic initialization of all statics of that TU must happen before that *something* is used. It could happen before main, or it could happen just before that first use of *something*, or anywhere in between.

Comment: The point of the example is that it shows an auto-registration mechanism in which nothing in the TU is odr-used, and which relies on compiler-specific behaviour to work properly.

Comment: @Jeremy Exactly. The example relies on the compiler to initialize the static variable, since standard does not guarantee that it would be initialized at all.